# A combinatoric identity involving Eulerian and Stirling numbers

Tags: combinatorics, summation, stirling-numbers, eulerian-numbers

Let
$$
A_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left\langle\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right\rangle x^{n-k}
$$
Eulerian Polynomials
and $$
\left\langle\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right\rangle
$$ are Eulerian numbers.

I want to ask whats the proof of this interesting equation?
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\langle\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right\rangle x^{n-k}=(1-x)^{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left\{\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right\} k !\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^{k}
$$

I have a reference [https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~tauraso/AMM/AMM11007.pdf](https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/%7Etauraso/AMM/AMM11007.pdf)

In this paper(American Mathematical Monthly Problem)  there are a similar approach. It solves 2 seperate equation with induction.You can look at it.

When i solved this equation in same way ,i couldnt reach a recurence relation about eulerian and stirling numbers. Maybe i go wrong in somewhere.
So can you help me ?

Comment: The formula is proved in the paper & the recurrence formulea are used/derived... so what is the question ?

Comment: i am sorry :) i am a beginner in combinatorics. When i take n instead of n+1   and  k  instead of k+1  in the paper as you see and apply same methods  i couldn't find the solution. Where do i make mistake?

Comment: Just replace $n \rightarrow n-1$ in all the equations & you will get
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\langle\begin{array}{l} n \\ k \end{array}\right\rangle = (n+1-k)
\left\langle\begin{array}{l} n-1 \\ k \end{array}\right\rangle + k
\left\langle\begin{array}{l} n-1 \\ k \end{array}\right\rangle.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another proof for the curious. We seek to verify that
(with $n\ge 1$, $n=0$ holds by inspection)

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left\langle n \atop k \right\rangle x^{n-k}
= (1-x)^n \sum_{k=0}^n {n\brace k} k!
\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^k.$$

We get using standard EGFs for the RHS

$$n! [z^n] (1-x)^n
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!} k!
\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^k
\\ = n! [z^n] (1-x)^n
\sum_{k=0}^n (\exp(z)-1)^k
\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^k.$$

Now because $\exp(z)-1 = z+\cdots$ we have $(\exp(z)-1)^k = z^k +
\cdots$ so when $k\gt n$ there is no contribution to the coefficient
extractor and we get

$$n! [z^n] (1-x)^n
\sum_{k\ge 0} (\exp(z)-1)^k
\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^k
\\ = n! [z^n] (1-x)^n
\frac{1}{1-(\exp(z)-1)x/(1-x)}
\\ = n! [z^n] (1-x)^n
\frac{1-x}{1-x-(\exp(z)-1)x}
\\ = n! [z^n] (1-x)^n
\frac{1-x}{1-x \exp(z)}
\\ = n! [z^n] \frac{1-x}{1-x\exp(z(1-x))}.$$

On the other hand we have for the LHS by the mixed GF of the Eulerian
numbers

$$n! [z^n] \sum_{k=0}^n x^{n-k}
[w^k] \frac{w-1}{w-\exp((w-1)z)}$$

Now we have $\left\langle n \atop k \right\rangle = 0$ when $k\ge n$ so
this is

$$n! [z^n] x^n \sum_{k\ge 0} x^{-k}
[w^k] \frac{w-1}{w-\exp((w-1)z)}
\\ = n! [z^n] x^n \frac{1/x-1}{1/x-\exp((1/x-1)z)}
\\ = n! [z^n] x^n \frac{1-x}{1-x\exp((1/x-1)z)}
\\ = n! [z^n] \frac{1-x}{1-x\exp((1/x-1)zx)}
\\ = n! [z^n] \frac{1-x}{1-x\exp((1-x)z)}.$$

The LHS is the same as the RHS and we have the claim.

**Addendum.** We have

$$n! [z^n] [w^k] \frac{w-1}{w-\exp((w-1)z)}
\\ = n! [z^n] [w^{k+1}] \frac{w-1}{1-\exp((w-1)z)/w}
\\ = n! [z^n] [w^{k+1}] (w-1)
\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{1}{w^q} \exp(q(w-1)z)
\\ = [w^{k+1}]
\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{1}{w^q} q^n (w-1)^{n+1}
= \sum_{q\ge 0} [w^{k+1+q}] q^n (w-1)^{n+1}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k} \sum_{q=1}^{n-k} (-1)^q q^n {n+1\choose k+1+q}.$$

This justifies that $\left\langle n \atop k \right\rangle = 0$ when $k\ge
n$ and hence the two coefficient extractors combined return  zero in that
case as  claimed.

Comment: that's a great answer.congrulations. i will try to understand it :)